# Is there any way to detect the monitor state in Windows (on or off)?

Tags: windows, winapi

Does anyone know if there is an API to get the current monitor state (on or off) in Windows (XP/Vista/2000/2003)?

All of my searches seem to indicate there is no real way of doing this.

[This thread](http://www.promixis.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1282.html) tries to use [GetDevicePowerState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372690(VS.85).aspx) which according to Microsoft's docs does not work for display devices.

In Vista I can listen to [GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373195(VS.85).aspx) but I do not seem to get events when the monitor is turned off manually.

In XP I can hook into `WM_SYSCOMMAND` `SC_MONITORPOWER`, looking for status 2. This only works for situations where the system triggers the power off.

The WMI `Win32_DesktopMonitor` class does not seem to help out as well.

**Edit**: Here is [a discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/browse_thread/thread/6d3e0a0828e68b89/d095095f5244bab4?lnk=gst&q=GetDevicePowerState++monitor#d095095f5244bab4) on comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32 indicating there is no reliable way of doing this.

Anyone else have any other ideas?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328490/monitoring-a-displays-state-in-python

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this information? Maybe we could help solve the real problem. Regards.

Comment: To estimate roughly the power consumed by monitors physically connected to a computer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[GetDevicePowerState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *sometimes* works for monitors. If it's present, you can open the `\\.\LCD` device. Close it immediately after you've finished with it.

Essentially, you're out of luck—there is no reliable way to detect the monitor power state, short of writing a device driver and filtering all of the power IRPs up and down the display driver chain. And that's not very reliable either.

Comment: I think this is the closest answer to the question. Its a real failure of the hardware mfgs for not giving us that level of comms in the DVI standard.

Comment: Seriously though, close it immediately after you've finished with it. I once broke presentation mode on Michael Dell's laptop by failing to do that :)

Comment: Documentation for [GetDevicePowerState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getdevicepowerstate) says "This function cannot be used to query the power state of a display device."

Comment: Unless they changed something between Windows Vista and now (which is possible), the documentation's wrong. The function cannot be used to _reliably_ query the power state of a display device, but it did work on a majority of the (several thousand) computers we tried it on.

Answer (score 13):

You could hook up a webcam, point it at your screen and do some analysis on the images you receive ;)

Comment: But then you may mistake reflections for screen action.. I think you're turning a device driver problem into an image processing problem.. I LIKE IT :)

Comment: This technique has been used to monitor racks full of equipment in remote locations. Point a camera at the rack, and watch for "unusual" changes in the indicator lights. Its brute force, but in some cases it is the only reasonable answer.

Answer (score 7):

Before doing anything based on the monitor state, just remember that users can use a machine with remote desktop of other systems that don't require a monitor connected to the machine - so don't turn off any visualization based on the monitor state.

Comment: The windows API allow you to figure out if a monitor is "real" or not.  See: DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER.

Comment: Remote desktop apps still affect the screen saver, don't they? (At least RealVNC does.) I know windows's own Remote Desktop sessions uses another system, so things might differ there.

Answer (score 7):

**You can't.**

Look like all monitor power capabilities connected to the **"power safe mode"**
After searching i found **[here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/showthread.php?p=755126)** code that connecting between **SC_MONITORPOWER** message and system values (post number 2)
I use the code to testing if the system values is changing when i am manually switch off the monitor.

```
int main()
{
    for(;monitorOff()!=1;)
        Sleep(500);
    return 0;
}//main
```

And the code is never stopped, no matter how long i am switch off my monitor.
There the code of monitorOff function:

```
int monitorOff()
{
    const GUID MonitorClassGuid =
        {0x4d36e96e, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 
            {0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18}};

    list<DevData> monitors;
    ListDeviceClassData(&MonitorClassGuid, monitors);

    list<DevData>::iterator it = monitors.begin(),
                            it_end = monitors.end();
    for (; it != it_end; ++it)
    {
        const char *off_msg = "";

        //it->PowerData.PD_PowerStateMapping
        if (it->PowerData.PD_MostRecentPowerState != PowerDeviceD0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }//for

    return 0;
}//monitorOff
```

**Conclusion :** when you manually switch of the the monitor, **you cant catch it by windows** (if there is no unusual driver interface for this), because all windows capabilities is connected to **"power safe mode"**.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows XP or later you can use the IMSVidDevice Interface.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd376775(VS.85).aspx

(not sure if this works in Sever 2003)

Comment: Any examples how to use this interface?

Comment: There is but it is Windows XP only, it is part of the directx sdk.

Comment: @Fraser Are you sure about that? I can't seem to locate it in the June 2010 SDK: https://i.imgur.com/NPK0jjw.png

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck - yes it is/was part of the Directx9 SDK

Answer (score 1):

With Delphi code, you can detect invalid monitor geomerty while standby in progress:

```
i := 0
('Monitor'+IntToStr(i)+': '+IntToStr(Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect.Left)+', '+
IntToStr(Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect.Top)+', '+
IntToStr(Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect.Right)+', '+
IntToStr(Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect.Bottom))
```

Results:

Monitor geometry before standby:

```
Monitor0: 0, 0, 1600, 900
```

Monitor geometry while standby in Deplhi7:

```
Monitor0: 1637792, 4210405, 31266576, 1637696
```

Monitor geometry while standby in DeplhiXE:

```
Monitor0: 4211194, 40, 1637668, 1637693
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old post but if it can help someone, I have found a solution to detect a screen being available or not : the Connecting and Configuring Displays (CCD) API of Windows.

It's part of `User32.ddl` and the interesting functions are `GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes` and `QueryDisplayConfig`. It give us all informations that can be viewed in the Configuration Panel of windows.

In particular the `PathInfo` contains a `TargetInfo` property that have a `targetAvailable` flag. This flag seems to be correctly updated on all the configurations I have tried so far.

This allow you to know the state of every screens connected to the PC and set their configurations.

[Here a CCD wrapper for .Net](https://github.com/regueiro/CCDWrapper/tree/master/CCDWrapper)

Comment: This did not work for me with single Dell monitor connected via DisplayPort to Windows 10 PC.  targetAvailable was always 1 regardless of monitor power state. Thanks for sharing your results though.

Answer (score 1):

I added a vcl timer to the form to check monitor status.

it simply worked for me for one monitor system. hope this helps someone.

```
function GetDevicePowerState(hDevice: DWORD; var pfOn: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
external kernel32;

function CheckMonitorState: boolean;
var
Hwnd: THandle;
Stat: LongBool;
begin
Hwnd := CreateFile('\\.\LCD', 0, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if Hwnd <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  GetDevicePowerState(Hwnd, Stat);
Result := Stat;
CloseHandle(Hwnd);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckMonitorState then
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Monitor ON')
  else
    Memo1.Lines.Append('Monitor OFF');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your monitor has some sort of built-in USB hub, you could try and use that to detect if the monitor is off/on.
This will of course only work if the USB hub doesn't stay connected when the monitor is consider "off".