# How to programmatically set Windows 10 Night Light in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, pinvoke

Does anyone know how to invoke native function to set Windows 10 Night Light option to True ?

Seems like `SetDeviceGammaRamp()` is the only option.
If so, then how to set the value to pass to the function in order to have reddish screen?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359607/correct-usage-of-setdevicegammaramp) for some relevant information. You would use Platform Invoke (pinvoke) to invoke the unmanaged function from managed code in the same way as any other.

Comment: I would suspect that's your option. I'd guess night light is just a service which does exactly that.

Comment: Duplicate to https://superuser.com/questions/1200222/configure-windows-creators-update-night-light-via-registry

Comment: @LexLi no, I'm asking for .net solution