# GetDevicePowerState doesn't work

Tags: winapi, device

I'm trying to check if monitor is connected to the power or not.
I'm trying that code but even if I try on different machine, it always return me that monitor is off.

What could be the problem?

This is what i try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    POINT p = { 0, 0 };
    HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromPoint(p, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);

    if (monitor == NULL) 
        std::cout << "No monitor found for point (0, 0)\n";
    else {
        BOOL result;
        if(GetDevicePowerState(monitor,&result)){
            std::cout << "Monitor is on!: \n";
        }else{
            std::cout << "Monitor is off!: \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save memory by using the same variable as parameter and return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the function correctly. You are passing the address of a `BOOL` variable as the second parameter, but also assigning the function return value to that variable. The `pfOn` parameter is not the same thing as the function return value

You need to modify the code to separate those two distinct values.

```
if (GetDevicePowerState(monitor,&result))
{
    ... do something with result
}
else
{
    ... the call to GetDevicePowerState failed, result is ill-defined
}
```

By similar token, you are not checking the return value of `GetMonitorInfo`.

Now, once we fix this, the code might look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    POINT p = { 0, 0 };
    HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromPoint(p, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);

    if (monitor == NULL) 
        std::cout << "No monitor found for point (0, 0)\n";
    else {

        MONITORINFOEX info;
        BOOL result;
        if (GetDevicePowerState(monitor,&result))
        {
            std::cout << "Result = " << result << "\n";
            if(result==TRUE){
                std::cout << "Monitor is on!: \n";
            }else{
                std::cout << "Monitor is off!: \n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Call to GetDevicePowerState failed\n";
        }

        if (GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info))
        {
            std::cout << "Monitor: " << info.szDevice << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Call to GetMonitorInfo failed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run this program, the output is:

```
Call to GetDevicePowerState failed
Call to GetMonitorInfo failed
```

So, why does the call to `GetDevicePowerState` fail? Well, because that function does not accept an `HMONITOR`. It accepts a handle to a device and an `HMONITOR` does not meet the requirement.

And why does the call to `GetMonitorInfo` fail? Well, you failed to do what the documentation told you to do. It says:

> You must set the cbSize member of the structure to sizeof(MONITORINFO) or sizeof(MONITORINFOEX) before calling the GetMonitorInfo function.

Comment: sorry but it continue giving me the same result! :(

Comment: Read my latest update. Step 1 has to be to learn how to call the functions properly and perform error checking.

Comment: ok, so i can't use GetDevicePowerState to check if monitor is connected to power.. how can i solve?

Comment: That's a different question, which has been asked before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203355/is-there-any-way-to-detect-the-monitor-state-in-windows-on-or-off). I think I answered the question you asked here.