# GetDevicePowerState what should hDevice enter?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am new to python Ctypes, i use `GetDevicePowerState`  function I don't know how to input hDevice ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-TW/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getdevicepowerstate

```
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

Kernel32 = ct.WinDLL('Kernel32')

Kernel32.GetDevicePowerState.argtypes = w.HANDLE,w.BOOLEAN
Kernel32.GetDevicePowerState.restype = w.BOOLEAN

hDevice = 'USB'
pfOn = True

result = Kernel32.GetDevicePowerState(hDevice,pfOn)

print(result)
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20047647/437212 (This is a suggestion that you could have done a little more research, here and on the internet.)

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of handles

Comment: You might need to research Windows API "handles" then, and then ask _that_ question. Handles are not limited to this API, but are a Windows programming API concept. For USB you can get a device handle back from another call. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/working-with-usb-devices

Comment: It turned out to be handle but I don't know how to write it I'm a newbie

Comment: This is a fundamental Win32 concept best researched in the usual places. SO is not really a good place for tutorials.