# C++ - is display off?

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-7, windows-xp

I'm trying to figure out whether the display is off. Just to clarify what I mean by *display is off*; windows has the *Turn off the display* options in the power options.

I've looked at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx), and noticed `SC_MONITORPOWER` parameter which "*Sets the state of the display* ". Is there any way to get the state of the display?

### Notes

I need to support all windows version >= `XP`

Comment: I don't think there is a way, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/204453/4603670

Comment: 10x. Great post. Missed it.