# receive Monitor On event/message in a win32/wpf app

Tags: c#, winapi, visual-c++

When the monitor is turned off, i receive a 'WM_SYSCOMMAND' message with 'SC_MONITORPOWER' as the wParam and '2'  as the lParam. However no message is received when the monitor is turned back on.

Is there a different command that I should be listening for in case of 'MONITOR ON' message or is there any other way of determining when a monitor connected to the PC is turned on/off?

Comment: I don't know if this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203355/is-there-any-way-to-detect-the-monitor-state-in-windows-on-or-off

Comment: yes..seems like there is no way of doing what i want.