# I have multiple monitors connected, when any of the connected monitor is power off, notify with the pop up message using windows message.(WindowProc)

Tags: windows, winapi

I have multiple monitors connected to my main monitor, if any of the connected monitor goes off(power off state). It should be notified. I have tried with several messages like WM_DEVICECHANGE, WM_POWERBROADCAST and WM_DEVMODECHANGE. But nothing seemed to work, because WM_DEVICECHANGE notifies when the connection is removed/connected and WM_POWERBROADCAST also didn't seem to work, when my second monitor goes to power off state.

Comment: Probably one for Meta , look at this one [What can I Ask Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Related/Dupe: [Is there any way to detect the monitor state in Windows (on or off)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203355/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau that link talks about using 
GetDevicePowerState(..), which didn't work while I tried to fetch the 2nd monitor power status.

Comment: @DeepikaRKrishna read it more carefully, it mentions a few things, and links to other questions that also talk about various approaches